# Can I use Amiibo as a playable character in Smash?

Tags: wii-u, super-smash-bros-4, amiibo

I recall seeing an ad of bunch of teenagers playing Smash as their Amiibo characters, but I can't seem to find a way to actually do it.
I know I can play in a team with Amiibo and have it be controller by the CPU, but is it possible to control it myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is impossible to control the Amiibo character.
I checked the electronic manual and it specifically mentions that Amiibo can be used as a Figurine Player and cannot be controlled.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find the electronic manual online, so I can't link it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked Nintendo's FAQ on amiibo, and confirm you can't play as your amiibo.  I felt so let down when I saw that you cannot use your them as a player.  It's like you have your own Poke'mon but for Smash Bros.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no you can't. Trust me, I just figured this out as well. They're like a pet, you can train them and battle other pets. I bought 5 today. It's like a Pokemon I can train it and everything. Until I log on and find out all I do is watch it fight and level up. You can't play as them, but you can fight beside them. But still, I just spent about $60, and the commercial on TV showed teens playing as their Amiibo, which is apparently wrong. So you can not be them.